# implementing multi threading to execute a for loop in threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a list of type string with 65000 strings. I need to loop thru all of these string and do some task. Running on for loop to iterate 65000 times is taking more time. So I would like to start 4 to 5 threads which can divide this list data and execute individually 10000 to 15000 data. I have understood about starting and aborting a thread using Thread class. But I am not clear about multi threading and thread management and implementing locking machanism so that multiple threads does not work on same data and sequence of execution wont alter.

I am new to threading concepts. Please help.Any code examples will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Don't use `Thread`! Use `Task` instead and let the framework handle how the tasks are handled on threadpool. Also if you are just reading from the list you won't need locking.

Comment: Why not use .NET's `Parallel.For` or PLINQ? Why write your own?

Comment: Yes `Parallel.For` is even better for this situation.

Comment: @EpicSam :Hi, does locking needed if Queue is used instead of List?

Comment: @Naveen Locking in general should not be needed if you are only reading and not modifying a collection. If you are unsure about your specific situation you can look at the msdn page of your data structure. The page for Queue<T> is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *PLinq* (Parallel Linq) as a first try:

```
  myList
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .ForAll(item => MyRoutine(item));
```

Another option is `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
  ParallelOptions op = new ParallelOptions() {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
  };

  Parallel.ForEach(myList, op, item => MyRoutine(item));
```

**Edit**: be careful, many classes are not *thread safe*, `List<T>` included (see comments below). If you want to materialize data into the list, do it with *PLinq*:

```
  List<string> listStrings = myList
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .Select(item => item.text.Substring(5, item.text.Length)))
    .ToList(); // <- this is thread safe
```

Comment: hi, I have tired your first code. but its not executing all 65000 records, its giving result around 64790 records only, any clue?

Comment: @Naveen kumar: do you have *exceptions thrown*?

Comment: no exceptions are thrown. code is executing but result is not accurate

Comment: @Naveen kumar: what code do you execute? It can be *not thread safe* (e.g. deadlock or race conditions).

Comment: var listStrings = new List<strings>(); // this list will have 65000 strings
var data = new List<string>();

  ParallelOptions op = new ParallelOptions()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(listStrings, op, item => data.Add(item.text.Substring(5, item.text.Length)));

=====this is my code which is giving wrong output, my data list is not having 65000 strings after completion

Comment: how to understand whether some thing is thread safe or not?

Comment: @Naveen kumar: `List<T>` is *not thread safe*, so `data.Add(...)` can bring problems; do not work with `List<T>` directly, let PLinq do it for you (see my edit, please)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131229/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-dmitry-bychenko).